# Quadratic roots

Tags: roots, quadratics

I've come across the expression $α/β + β/α$ which I've never seen before. I've tried to find out as much as I can about it but I've only found information on the other expressions for quadratic roots $α+β$ and $αβ$ and regular (non maths) sites in russian.
The quadratic in particular this expression is in relation to is $$2x^2 - 3x - 1 = 0$$
A fairly simple quadratic, but I don't know how to use the expression $α/β + β/α$.
Can anyone explain it's use and how to calculate it?

Comment: sorry did you want to find the value of $\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta} + \dfrac{\beta}{\alpha}$? or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:$$\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta} + \dfrac{\beta}{\alpha} = \dfrac{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}{\alpha\beta} = \dfrac{(\alpha + \beta)^2-2\alpha\beta}{\alpha\beta}$$

Comment: So the use of $α/β + β/α$ is to calculate? I think I get the mathematics behind it now, but not the use.

Comment: sorry @kanuut I couldn't find any significance of that expression.

Comment: I suppose that ,given a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ the roots of which being $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you just have $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} + \frac{\beta}{\alpha}=\frac{b^2}{ac}-2$ without needing to compute the roots.